# Excel VBA Error - Cell(R, C).Paste

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm writing code in Workbook0.Worksheet1 to copy a cell from Workbook1.WorkSheet1 to a cell in Workbook2.Worksheet1

Here is the code:

```
Sub CopyInfo()  
    Dim WSCopy As Worksheet  
    Dim WSPaste As Worksheet  
    Set WSCopy = Workbooks(Cells(3, 4).Value).Worksheets("Sheet1")  
    Set WSPaste = Workbooks(Cells(4, 4).Value).Worksheets("Sheet1")  
    RowCopy = Range(Cells(11, 3)).Row  
    ColCopy = Range(Cells(11, 3)).Column  
    RowPaste = Range(Cells(11, 4)).Row  
    ColPaste = Range(Cells(11, 4)).Column  
    Data = "Data"  
    While Data <> ""  
        Data = WSCopy.Cells(RowCopy, ColCopy)  
        WSPaste.Cells(RowPaste, ColPaste) = Data  
        RowCopy = RowCopy + 1  
        ColCopy = ColCopy  
        RowPaste = RowPatse  
        ColPaste = ColPaste + 1  
    Wend  
End Sub
```

It works fine the first iteration, at second iteration sends an error.

Hope someone shows me where is my mistake.

Comment: Which line is giving you an error?

Comment: Can you step through the code to confirm all values are what you expect? My guess you have a null reference or similar.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing the issue is caused by a typo in your code on this line:

```
RowPaste = RowPatse
```

Since VBA does not require you to declare your variables, it is assigning to `RowPaste` the value of a new Empty Variant `RowPatse`. Hence the code breaks the second time through.

To avoid this sort of typo problem, you can add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module. This will cause the compiler to throw an error any time an undeclared variable is called in your code.

This issue aside, the lines

```
ColCopy = ColCopy
RowPaste = RowPaste
```

can just be removed because they are doing absolutely nothing.